# Migrate from flatfiles (library.01.pm, library.02.pm ...) to Git

Tags: git, perl, version-control, migration

I started to work in an legacy environment where the responsible developers didn't use versioning.
He kind of used his own versioning, by saving the written files in a ascending way.

For example:

First version: Library.01.pm

Second Version: Library.02.pm

Currently everything is saved in a folder which can be nested.

> ->libs (directory)
>
> --> parser.pm (file)
>
> --> config (directory)
>
> ----> general.pm (file in subdirectory)

and so on.

Our goal is to take our "versioning" to Git. Our current idea is to take the existing versions and subdirectory structure and make a commit for each version.
We tried git-fast-import, but couldn't take the existing folder structure with us. Maybe this is wrong approach anyway.

What do think about that idea?

Comment: "the responsible developers didnt use versioning" - responsible developers always use versioning.

Comment: I completely agree with you... well they kinda used their own kind of "versioning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use perl to read a file structure and write a new scripit which can be replayed in git bash (which also comes with perl).

Here is an example of a script that would work

I start with an old file structure and an git structure as a directory structure only.  From my git folder I use the find command to find all the files in the old structure, then iterate over them in the perl script.

```
G01103266@BDSPUKL70343008 /cygdrive/c/work/temp/git
$ find ../old/
../old/
../old/libs
../old/libs/config
../old/libs/config/config_file_01.pm
../old/libs/config/config_file_02.pm
../old/libs/config/config_file_03.pm
../old/libs/lib_file.01.pm
../old/libs/lib_file.02.pm
../old/libs/lib_file.03.pm
```

Then using the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use English;

print "hello greg\n";

undef $/;

my $content = <ARGV>;
my @files = split(/\n/,$content);
for my $tag ('01','02','03') {
        for my $file (@files) {
                if ($file =~ /$tag/) {
                        my $newFile = $file;
                        $newFile =~ s/_$tag//sg;
                        $newFile =~ s/..\/old\///sg;
                        print "cp$_  $file  $newFile\n";
                }
        }
        print "git add --all\n";
        print "git commit -a -m \"commint from tag $tag\"\n";
}
```

Which create the following replay script:

```
G01103266@BDSPUKL70343008 /cygdrive/c/work/temp/git
find ../old/ | ../import.pl
hello greg
cp  ../old/libs/config/config_file_01.pm  libs/config/config_file.pm
cp  ../old/libs/lib_file.01.pm  libs/lib_file.01.pm
git add --all
git commit -a -m "commint from tag 01"
cp  ../old/libs/config/config_file_02.pm  libs/config/config_file.pm
cp  ../old/libs/lib_file.02.pm  libs/lib_file.02.pm
git add --all
git commit -a -m "commint from tag 02"
cp  ../old/libs/config/config_file_03.pm  libs/config/config_file.pm
cp  ../old/libs/lib_file.03.pm  libs/lib_file.03.pm
git add --all
git commit -a -m "commint from tag 03"
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually we did it similar thanks to your idea. Our idea using git-fast-import was kinda wrong.